# Nested object scope and dynamic reference in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've recently been working with vanilla javascript to help myself learn the language, and I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding exactly how objects 'inner variables' can be defined and what exactly other functions can see.

As an example, lets say that we have a gameData variable:

```
let gameData = {
    resourcesArray: [wood, stone]
}
```

With 'wood' and 'stone' defined as:

```
let wood = {
    name: 'Wood',
    amount: '0,
}

let stone = {
    name: 'Stone',
    amount: 0,
}
```

As a test of the scope of these variables specifically, lets say in this situation there is a 'farm' building defined as such.

```
let farm = {
    name: "Farm"
    amount: 0,
    cost: {
        'Wood': 10,
        'Stone': 5,
    },
}
```

How would I then, be able to create a function along the lines of *buyBuilding(building)*, pass it the farm object, and have it properly match the names of the 'farm' costs with the resources stored in resourcesArray and deduct the cost?

Ideally this function would be able to handle 'buildings' with **many different resources and costs** added in the future which is why I'm looking for an intelligent way to do this without just hardcoding a buy function for every 'building' that would be added.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shortly without code. You need to make it more OO, create parent class `Resource`. Include function `deductCost`. And in class game you need to add function `buyBuilding` which will serve buildings counting and cost deducting from resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each cost you'll have to deduct the amount from the global gameData context... something like so:

```js
const wood = {
  name: 'Wood',
  amount: 500, // Start out with enough to build stuff
}

const stone = {
  name: 'Stone',
  amount: 300, // Start out with enough to build stuff
}

const gameData = {
  resourcesArray: [wood, stone],
}

const farm = {
  name: "Farm",
  amount: 0,
  cost: {
    'Wood': 10,
    'Stone': 5,
  },
}

function buyBuilding(thing = farm) {
  console.log(`Time to build a ${thing.name}!`);

  Object.keys(thing.cost).forEach(resource => {
    const amount = thing.cost[resource];
    console.log(`* This requires ${amount} ${resource}...`);
    const gameResource = gameData.resourcesArray.find(r => r.name === resource);
    console.log(`  | You have ${gameResource.amount} ${resource} available.`);
    // @TODO Check if you have enough before deducting
    gameResource.amount -= amount;
    console.log(`  | Only ${gameResource.amount} ${resource} left now.`);
  });

  console.log(`New game state:`, gameData.resourcesArray);
}

// Do the actual building!
buyBuilding(farm);
```